# Master pages and applying adjustments to photo place holder frames in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I am working on a photobook right now in ID 2021 with the same size place holder frame and margins applied to all pages.

I want to increase my margin and the size of the photo frame and apply it to all. Is this possible?

I have a photo frame on the master page so I know where to place the images. I have all my photos laid out in the pages, but now I want to move them in 1/2" and possibly increase the size of the frame.

Can that be applied AFTER via Master Pages to all the photos after they've been laid out and linked? Apparently it won't let me move the frame on the master page and apply it to pages without losing the images.

The margin increase I can see, but if I move the placeholder frame on the master page, it doesn't seem to affect the pages it's been applied to.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it *should* be possible to move and resize a frame on a master page and thereby automatically apply the change to all pages using that master.

But it *only* works if you haven't scaled or moved the images on the individual pages!

[image]

I'm not aware of a way to make a frame follow the master page again once it has lost the connection.

There is another way you can gain control of the position of the images. By using an *Object Style*.

- Select the frame on the master page.
- In the *Object Styles* panel, click the *Create new style* button.
- Click the new object style to apply it to the frame on the master page.
- Enter the settings of the object style. Under *Size and Position Options*, set *Size > Adjust* to *Height & Width* and set *Position > Adjust* to *X & Y*.

  [image]

Now the images on all pages should get their size and position from the object style.

This means that if you move or scale *any* of the images with that object style (on a master page or an ordinary page), the object style will have *overrides* (a + by its name). If you then right-click the style and choose *Redefine Style* all images with that object style will move and scale accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see now that's its pretty essential for objects in Master Pages to really work you can't change the pages themselves manually if you plan to change the Master Page down the road. I was able to increase the frame size and apply it to all, but moving the object doesn't work since I have moved every page manually. If I try to reapply the Mater Page to all in order to move the frame on the page, for some reason all the photos disappear from within the object frame. I know it sounds confusing. Kind of hard to explain. This is super helpful for the future tho. Good info. Thanks!

Comment: I understand exactly what you mean. Reapplying the master will remove the placed image. (Remember to accept this answer if you feel it answers our question.)

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear what you're trying to achieve, but try to:

1. apply an object style to the photo frame on the master page and set that to auto-scale its image content
2. then, tick the `Adjust Layout` option when editing `Margins and Columns` on the master page

[image]